# What IntelliJ plugin contributes the "View as JSON" option?

Tags: intellij-idea

I used to see an option when right-clicking on JSON text in the Output console, *View as JSON*, which would open the line of text in a JSON edit tab. A while ago I disabled some plugins I don't use and now that option is gone.

Which plugin provides "View as JSON?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's the [`Show as...` plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7010?pr=)

> A small plugin to display formatted data out of the debugger.
>
> Uses IntelliJ's build-in formatting capabilities.  No more need to
> copy values from debugger to a file to format them there. Following
> formats are supported:
>
> - Xml
> - JSON
> - Base64 encoded JSON
> - Base64 encoded text
>
> Usage: While debugging, a new context menu item ("Show as") is
> added to every variable, allowing you to display the value of this
> variable formatted. The context menu item is available in debugger ->
> variables, debugger -> watches and when evaluating expressions.

[image: Show as...]

Comment: I might install that to give it a try, but I'm certain I never installed it before, so it can't be the source of behavior I used to have. And it doesn't seem to work from the Output console, does it?

Comment: @E-Riz I don't know any implicit one or otherwise that has similar functionality, but I'm not an encyclopedia :-). What you see in the inlined gif, is exactly the output console for a spring boot application.

Comment: This plug-in does the job. Thanks.

Comment: @E-Riz no problem, glad I could help. Cheers and have a nice weekend

Comment: No window pops up for me when pressing "Show as JSON".

Comment: @Peheje Do you get any error messages from the IDE? The only thing that comes to mind is that it may not be compatible with your installed version of IntelliJ, so please check the compatibility table. Also you can try to contact the plugin maintainer using the e-mail address specified on the plugin page.

Comment: No error messages presented. I'm on Intellij Community installed via Jetbrains Toolbox on MacOS. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Any news about this plugin? it is not maintained since last year. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The "Show as" plugin didn't work for me.

Alternatively, you can create "Show Type Renderers" in the IntelliJ preferences as follows:

[image]

Uncheck On-demand if you want to render your object as JSON without clicking "View".

Comment: Great solution, thank you! 
I created another renderer "default" above the JSON Renderer which uses default renderer so that not everything is automatically shown as JSON.